# .index() usage help, nested lists + slice?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Here I made two lists:

```
print(list) #[['5', '6', '7'], ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7']]
print(list4) #[['5', '6', '7'], ['3', '1', '8']]

index = str(list4[0:][0]).index(list[0][0])

print(index) #output: 2??
```

after putting it through .index() it returns 2, what is it returning?

Any suggestions as to how get obtain an index with the above intent? Are loops necessary in this case?

---

I also tried putting other '5's in the other nested list in list4 like this:

```
list4 = [['3', '1', '8'], '5', ['5', '2', 5]]
```

But it just gives giving me 2

Comment: Post working scripts when possible. Instead of printing the list with its value in a comment, assign the variable: `list= [['5', '6', '7'], ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7']]`. Why make us do that work?

Comment: What "above intent"?

Comment: Also, you didn't mention your expected result. I assume you want 0, but 2 is the proper answer if you really did want to convert to a string first.

Answer (score 1):

`list4[0:]` gives nothing, but the original list4, and `list[0:][0]` gives the first element of list4, which is `['5', '6', '7']`.

`list[0][0]` give '5', and you get the index of '5' in `str(['5', '6', '7'])`.
The index of 5 in `str(['5', '6', '7'])` is 2.

Answer (score 0):

`str(list4[0:][0])`

Because you wrapped this in `str()`, the result is of course a **string**:

```
"['5', '6', '7']"
```

`[` is the first character of this string.  (position 0)

`'` is the second character.  (position 1)

`5` is the third character.  (position 2)

Answer (score 0):

You've got the str() in the wrong place.

You are typing `str(list4[0:][0])` which turns it into the string "['5', '6', '7']".  The character '5' is at index 2 of that string.

I believe you want `str(......)` around the whole expression.  But I'm not sure why you want to convert it to a string.

Comment: yes you guessed right, I copied it from elsewhere and sleep deprived as I am I forgot to remove the str(), thank you for the answer though

Answer (score 0):

This is an easy one to work out with the python shell. First, I'm going to make this a working script, because of course you need a working script to debug things. And I'm not going to use `list` as a variable because it masks the `list` builtin function, hindering debug.

```
list1 = [['5', '6', '7'], ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7']]
list4 = [['5', '6', '7'], ['3', '1', '8']]

index = str(list4[0:][0]).index(list1[0][0])

print(index) #output: 2??
```

Then I'm going to enter interactive mode with `python3 -i test.py` and decompose that statement into parts

```
$ python3 -i test.py
2
>>> list4[0:][0]
['5', '6', '7']
>>> str(['5', '6', '7'])
"['5', '6', '7']"
```

There's your problem. You've got a string and "5" is in position 2. You can see that by exploding the string

```
>>> list("['5', '6', '7']")
['[', "'", '5', "'", ',', ' ', "'", '6', "'", ',', ' ', "'", '7', "'", ']']
```

To get the index, don't convert to a string

```
>>> list4[0:][0].index(list[0][0])
0
```

And you didn't need to make an anonymous copy of that list. All you're doing is burning cycles. This works the same

```
>>> list4[0].index(list[0][0])
0
```

Comment: to clarify making it list4[0] instead of how I had it gives you the same output only right here and that's what you meant by 'this works the same' right?

Also, yes, I think the problem I had was mainly overlooking the str()

Comment: Right. The problem was with "str". `list[0:][0]` copies the list, takes the 0th item of that copied list, and then throws the copied list away. Since all you wanted was that 0th item, the copy wasn't needed.

Answer (score -2):

The index method in Python is used to find the first occurrence of a specified value in a list. However, the way you're using it in your code is a bit confusing and not achieving what you might expect.

Let's break down what's happening in your code:

```
list = [['5', '6', '7'], ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7']]
list4 = [['5', '6', '7'], ['3', '1', '8']]

index = str(list4[0:][0]).index(list[0][0])
```

In the line where you're calculating index, you're doing the following:

list4[0:][0] is effectively the same as list4[0] because list4[0:] creates a shallow copy of the entire list4 list, and [0] then selects the first element of that copy, which is ['5', '6', '7'].
str(list4[0:][0]) converts this first element to a string, resulting in the string "['5', '6', '7']".
list[0][0] is the first element of the first list in list, which is the string '5'.
str(list4[0:][0]).index(list[0][0]) is looking for the substring '5' in the string "['5', '6', '7']". The substring '5' is found at index 2 in the string representation (counting starts at 0), which is why you're getting an output of 2.
If you want to find the index of the first list in list4 that contains the same first element as the first list in list, you would need to do something like this:

```
list = [['5', '6', '7'], ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7']]
list4 = [['5', '6', '7'], ['3', '1', '8']]

# Find the index of the first list in list4 that contains the same first element as the first list in list
target_value = list[0][0]
index = None
for i, sublist in enumerate(list4):
    if sublist[0] == target_value:
        index = i
        break

print(index)  # This should output 0, because the first element of the first list in list4 is '5'
```

In this code, we're using a loop with enumerate to iterate over the lists in list4 and compare the first element of each sublist with the first element of the first list in list. When we find a match, we break out of the loop and index will hold the index of the matching sublist.

Regarding your second example with list4 = [['3', '1', '8'], '5', ['5', '2', 5]], it's important to note that this list is not well-formed because it mixes strings and lists, and the last element contains both a string '5' and an integer 5. If you want to find the index of a list containing '5' as its first element, you would need to ensure that all elements in list4 are lists and that you're comparing like types (strings with strings, or integers with integers).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/ai-policy